# How to implement ZCAnimatedLabel's Default effect in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to animate Label. I want to animate like below.

[image]

This ZCAnimatedLabel  Library (https://github.com/overboming/ZCAnimatedLabel)  in objective-C I integrate this library in my project using pods. But I don't know how to implement this animation.

## EDIT

Now I remove my pods and create a bridging header and put a UIView in storyboard and give ZCAnimatedLabel as its class

[image]

What should I write in ViewController.swift to achieve this effect in ViewDidLoad

Comment: What's exactly the question? are you unable to use this library in Swift project? or are you trying to achieve this animation?

Comment: The code in objective-c I don't know that language. I want to achieve this animation

Comment: The library is in Objective-C but this is irrelevant. You can call Objective-C code from Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift (you don't even need any bridging if you're using a pod)

Comment: I know that way. Then how to create this effect in ViewController.swift I import ZCAnimatedLabel in above

Answer (score 0):

I did through `pod 'ZCAnimatedLabel'` and in **bridging header** file add `#import "ZCAnimatedLabel.h"`

Drag and drop `UIView` in your scene/xib and layout it the way you want.

```
import ZCAnimatedLabel
```

in your `UIViewController`, add `IBOutlet` and in scene/xib change your `UIView class` to the type of animated label you want. For `default` behavior change to `ZCAnimatedLabel` *class* and to animate add below code.

```
self.label.animationDuration = 1 // add animation duration
self.label.animationDelay = 1 // add seconds to delay
self.label.text = "some text"
self.label.startAppearAnimation()
```

and to stop animation

```
self.label.stopAnimation()
```

I started animation in `viewWillAppear` and stopped in `viewWillDisappear`.

Important note: I did this in swift 5